# Multiple dynamic nav tabs in angular with dynamic data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a grid whose data is fetched from API, on double click I want to open a new nav tab and show the data there.

Let's assume on double click I am calling the function onDoubleClick.

#component.ts

```
onDoubleClick(e){
this.data = e.data;
this.tabs.push(this.data.id);
}
```

component.html

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let tab for tabs">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">{Grid comes here}</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
{How i can show the tabs id here}
</div>
    </div>
```

I am using a loop for getting new tabs, but I am not able to get the associated id with it. I want to add as many as tabs I want and they should be generated by double-clicking on the grid row.
Please help.